# What is convergence interval $\sum_{1}^{\infty } (\frac{n - i}{i - 2n})^{n} (z-2)^{n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{1}^{\infty } (\frac{n - i}{i - 2n})^{n} (z-2)^{n} $
I tried and got $\frac{1}{2}\left |  z - 2\right | < 1$

It`s correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root test gives

$$\lim_\infty |a_n|^\frac 1n=\lim_\infty \left|\frac {n-i}{i-2n}\right|=$$

$$\lim_\infty \frac {\sqrt {n^2+1}}{\sqrt {1+4n^2}}=\frac {1}{2} $$

the radius of convergence is $R=2$

the series converges if
$$|z-2|<2$$